# Swap 3 divs and make the selection div go to the center

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swap

I have three `div`s and I want that every single time I click on any div, it will be swapped with a second div which is meant to be at the center.

I have tried like this and it doesn't work:

```js
function swapDiv(event, elem) {
  elem.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, elem.parentNode.secondChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="all-div-container">
  <div class="div1" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div2" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="div3" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

**1 2 3** and when I click **3** the result must be **1 3 2** from this result and I click on **1** it's must be **3 1 2**

Comment: You've labelled your question with `jQuery` but you are not using it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function swapDiv(event, elem) {
    // get all elements in .all-div-container
    const allElements = [...elem.parentElement.children];
    // get index of target elem
    const targetIndex = allElements.indexOf(elem);
    // get center element
    const centerElem = allElements[1];
    // exit from function if we clicked at center elem
    if (elem === centerElem) return;
    // move center element
    if (targetIndex === 0) {
        elem.parentElement.prepend(centerElem)
    } else {
        elem.parentElement.append(centerElem)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="all-div-container">
    <div class="div1" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="div2" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="div3" onclick="swapDiv(event,this);">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't just post code-only answers. What did the OP do wrong, and how did you solve it?

Comment: So you make a parent div all of them became a array that contain 3 children div, so the array was like [0][1][2], and you just swap the clicked div to [1], I don't know that did I understand it right ?

Comment: But thank you so much, I'm very appreciate

Comment: so, I don't do anything if I clicked on the second element, and when I clicked on the 1st or 3rd element, I just move the center one. If I clicked on the first element, then I move the center to the beginning, if I clicked on the third element, I move the center to the end

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".all-div-container > div").click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).index() == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    var $prev = $(this).prev();
    var $self = $(this).detach();
    $prev.before($self);
  });
});
```

```css
.all-div-container>div {
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-div-container">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```

You did not clarify what should happen if the first item is clicked. This code will swap the clicked element and the previous element.